# How do I pull data from an API in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I'm working on a little weather app project, but now that i've changed the code to make the long and lat change depending on you geo location, the button doesn't work. When i click it nothing happens, i can't even tell if the API is pulling the data. Here is my code as well as a codepen I made to fool around with.
http://codepen.io/lettda/pen/yaGaLx

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#reveal").on("click", function(){
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            lat = position.coords.latitude;
            long = position.coords.longitude;

        var long;
        var lat;
        var api = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat="+lat+"&lon="+long+"&appid=de61ccfbde0405f57d64dbb53323fccf";

                $.getJSON(api, function(data){
                    $(".message").html(JSON.stringify(data))
                });
            });
        };
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you might be getting some strange request issues due to trying to access the endpoint from codepen.  You can chase the error messages you receive either in the console or in the network panel-- that's where you can watch to see the call be executed, and evaluate if it succeeded, and if not, why.

Answer (score 0):

open your developer tools (in chrome press F12) and have a look into the console:

pen.js:4 getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() no longer work on insecure     origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as HTTPS. See https://.... for more details.

it's an simple cross origin problem